# Comparator inside sorted Stream method

Tags: java, java-8

It doesn't sort properly, actually it doesn't sort at all and I don't know why

this is Comparator class:

```
public class Komparator implements Comparator<BoardGame> {

    @Override
    public int compare(BoardGame o1, BoardGame o2) {
        System.out.println(o1.rating+"-"+o2.rating);
        return (int) (o2.rating-o1.rating);
    }
}
```

this is main part

```
List<BoardGame> games = Arrays.asList(
                new BoardGame("Terraforming Mars", 8.38, new BigDecimal("123.49"), 1, 5),
                new BoardGame("Codenames", 7.82, new BigDecimal("64.95"), 2, 8),
                new BoardGame("Puerto Rico", 8.07, new BigDecimal("149.99"), 2, 5),
                new BoardGame("Terra Mystica", 8.26, new BigDecimal("252.99"), 2, 5),
                new BoardGame("Scythe", 8.3, new BigDecimal("314.95"), 1, 5),
                new BoardGame("Power Grid", 7.92, new BigDecimal("145"), 2, 6),
                new BoardGame("7 Wonders Duel", 8.15, new BigDecimal("109.95"), 2, 2),
                new BoardGame("Dominion: Intrigue", 7.77, new BigDecimal("159.95"), 2, 4),
                new BoardGame("Patchwork", 7.77, new BigDecimal("75"), 2, 2),
                new BoardGame("The Castles of Burgundy", 8.12, new BigDecimal("129.95"), 2, 4)
        );

games.stream().filter(g->g.name.contains("a")).
                sorted(new Komparator()).
                map(g->g.name).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: `(int) (o2.rating-o1.rating)` is zero if the ratings are 8.26 and 8.3. That's not the way to deal with doubles in a comparator.

Comment: @khelwood It actually breaks the contract of `Comparator`, not only by returning wrong results, but also by not being transitive...

Comment: As a side note. use ForEachOrdered where the order matters as opposed to forEach.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @khelwood mentioned conversion to int like `(int)` just truncates decimal part. So you'd better change comparator to the following:

```
public class Komparator implements Comparator<BoardGame> {

  @Override
  public int compare(BoardGame o1, BoardGame o2) {
    System.out.println(o1.rating+"-"+o2.rating);
    if (o2.rating > o1.rating) return 1;
    if (o2.rating == o1.rating) return 0;
    return -1;
  }
}
```

And you can use debugger to go through your code to investigate an issue yourself.

Comment: The compiler doesn’t like when you have three conditional `return` statements without an unconditional one at the end. We know that one of these cases must apply, but the compiler doesn’t. On the other hand, you can do just [`return Double.compare(o2.rating, o1.rating);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare-double-double-). Since Java 1.4.

Comment: Yes, the last if could be replaced with direct return

Comment: This is what happens when you edit code in SO directly without using IDE. Updated answer

Comment: Still, a single `return Double.compare(o2.rating, o1.rating);` is even better.

Answer (score 3):

It would be a lot easier (and less error prone) if your would write it as:

```
games.stream()
     .filter(g->g.name.contains("a"))
     .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(BoardGame::getRating))
     ....
```

If you still want to use your comparator, use it with a proper method, like `Double::compare`

Comment: Yep, but I couldn't use getRating method

Comment: @wwww I don't get it, might care to explain a bit?

Comment: BoardGame class didn't have getRating() method and also I couldn't add this method